# Setup of static files in Heroku not working locally for Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I am setting up a web app with Django 2.2 in Heroku and I was able to deploy it successfully in production but the app doesn't load the css files locally every time I try to run `heroku local web`.

This is how I setup the configuration of my files in my Django app.

```
- src
  - live-static
       - media-root
       - static-root         
  - main_app
       - urls.py
       - wsgi.py
       - __init__.py
       - settings
           - __init__.py
           - base.py
           - local.py
           - production.py
  - pages
        - __init__.py
        - admin.py
        - apps.py
        - models.py
        - tests.py
        - views.py
        - templates
           - main_app
             - home.html    
  - templates
       - base.html
  - static
       - main_app
           - css
             -cover.css
           - img
             -myimage.jpg
       - admin
           - css
           - img
           - js
```

The following code is a snippet of the configurations from the production and local files:

```
production.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static', 'static-root')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


local.py


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static', 'static-root')
```

My css and jpg files are not rendered locally but they are rendered in production.

```
base.html
{% load static %}


 <link href="{% static 'main_app/css/cover.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
 <img src="{% static 'main_app/img/myimage.jpg' %}" >
```

I expect that when I run `heroku local web` I should be able to see the css and images rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about the answer to this question. But why don't you try typing in `heroku local:run python manage.py collectstatic` and see if it renders your page.

Sorry about posting this as an answer and not as a comment(don't have a high rep).

Comment: Your static files are collected by django using `python manage.py collectstatic`, which is done automatically when you push the repository to heroku. However, when you run heroku local web, they are not collected.

Comment: Do you have Heroku CLI installed? If yes, why don't you try `heroku local:run python` and see if the python interpreter boots up.

Comment: How could I force Django to make visible my css files?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the local.py file was missing the middleware `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` which is mandatory for visualizing the static files in Django.